# Looping through all my domains an changing pwd- access denied SET-QADUSER

Tags: powershell, quest

I have several domains and one admin account in each one. It is a great pain to log into each domain to change password every month..
I have therefore written a script that will connect to all domains and check to see if I have already changed the password or if I am still using the old one.
If I am using the old one the script should update it.

I connect to the domains (sequentially) with

```
$oldPassword = Read-Host "Enter old password" -AsSecureString
$newPassword = Read-Host "Enter new password" -AsSecureString
$oldCredentials = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "$domain\$adminusername",$oldPassword
Connect-QADService -Service $domain -Credential $oldCredentials
```

and if I get a successfull connection with $oldcredentials I try to change pwd with

```
GET-QADUSER $adminusername | SET-QADUSER -UserPassword $newPassword
```

I am guessing that I am not passing the secure string correctly to SET-QADUSER but I've found no documentation on another way to do it.

Please advice:)

Comment: `SET-QADUSER -UserPassword` accept `[string]` type not `[System.Security.SecureString]`. Try to pass just a string as password.

Comment: That's right! Thank you! if you formulate this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Posted as an answer. Glad to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SET-QADUSER -UserPassword` accept `[string]` type not `[System.Security.SecureString].`

Try to pass just a `string` as password.

Comment: Thank you very much for the pointer:) I ended up passing it as


   GET-QADUSER $adminusername | SET-QADUSER -UserPassword $newCredentials.GetNetworkCredential().Password